# Lamp changing color in bge

Tags: game-engine

How do I make a lamp constantly changing colours in bge? I need to make it cycle through the rainbow. Like in RGB gaming pcs.

Comment: keyframe  the colors by hovering over it and pressing I.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand

Comment: oh sorry nvm, i didn't realize it was game engine

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in BGE using an action actuator.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387475783838466051/597625497622544384/animatelightscolouration.blend

However I think there's a bug before 2.78 that doesn't allow you to do this.